# Azure APIM Calls are failing while connecting to load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-front-door, azure-ilb

We have hosted all our APIs in APIM and we have around 150 services hosted on to this APIM. All of sudden, from past few days we are seeing a lot of failures with a glitch of 2 minutes across with various API calls with error  "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.***.*.***.443 {This is a load balancer IP} *Masked the ip for security purpose.

So our architecture is something like this.
Customers=>AFD=>APIM=>Express route==>Load Balancer=>Backend systems.

We checked all possible logs but not able to find the RCA for this. Can you please suggest the RCA

Comment: The two minutes is likely a timeout on the backend system.  If you're suddenly seeing this it might be a few different things.  SNAT port exhaustion on the backend system if you've been seeing traffic steadily increasing over time.  It may be a networking issue, or an issue in the load balancer.

Comment: When you see the "connection attempt failed" are you able to see that in the APIM?  Are you able to see the connection attempt in the load balancer?

Comment: I am able to see that in the APIM logs